# Hide / show text instead of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover the pseudo - link from the top menu I want to display the corresponding `text` instead of `image`.

I got something similar.

Faced with the problem that the text does not rise to the
place the images and the script is being processed
moves down to the lower block content.

```
$('.spoiler').hide();
$('.pseudo-top-menu .pseudo-link').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $('.t' +index).fadeOut();
        $('.t' +index+ '+.spoiler').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;

        $('.t' +index+ '+.spoiler').fadeOut();  
       $('.t' +index).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v3k8re1p/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have span floating over image, make span `position:absolute`, and container `postion:relative`

```
.teasers-menu li{
    position:relative;
}

.teaser, .spoiler { 
     position:absolute;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v3k8re1p/7/